# Unable to read spark temp table data on databricks notebook

Tags: azure, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have created a dataframe "df" and a temp table `df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_table")` in azure databricks notebook. Then I'm writing a select query on that temp table using

```
dbutils.notebook.exit("""select col1, col4 from temp_table""").
```

Now, when I try to run this notebook from another notebook, I'm getting the error

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: temp_table.

How this can be resolved?

Comment: you can write that select query inside spark.sql("query"). why are you writing it inside dbutils.notebook.exit("query").

Comment: Are you trying to access that table in the same notebook and same session?

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya No, I'm having the temp table on another notebook and calling that notebook from master notebook.

Comment: I've found the answer guys, I just created a global temp view and used "global_temp.table_name" while writing the select statement. Now when I call the temp table notebook from master notebook, it is not throwing any error and able to read the data.